# How can I add a hint to show after a few incorrect guesses?

Tags: python

```
print("\t \t \t What's the password?")
print("\t you have 5 chances to get it right! \n")

secret_word = "green"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False
hintA = "Ashtons' favorite color"
print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)
#while loop
while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
  if guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input("Enter guess: ")
    guess_count += 1
  #elif guess_count == 2:
    #print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)
  
  else:
    out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
  print("You have been locked out!")
else:
  print("Correct password!")
```

I don't how to add a hint after like 2 or 3 guesses because without it would be impossible to do. Also the stuff in `#` was my attempt

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this :

```
print("\t \t \t What's the password?")
print("\t you have 5 chances to get it right! \n")

secret_word = "green"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False
hintA = "Ashtons' favorite color"
#while loop
while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
  if guess_count < guess_limit:
    if guess_count == 2:
      print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)
    guess = input("Enter guess: ")
    guess_count += 1
  #elif guess_count == 2:
    #print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)
  
  else:
    out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
  print("You have been locked out!")
else:
  print("Correct password!")
```

Comment: You need to remove the `print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)` before the while loop or else, the hint gets displayed before 2 guesses

Answer (score 0):

Move your input outside the `if...else` statements and change the position of the `if...else` statements.

```
print("\t \t \t What's the password?")
print("\t you have 5 chances to get it right! \n")

secret_word = "green"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False
hintA = "Ashtons' favorite color"
#while loop
while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
  guess = input("Enter guess: ")
    
  if guess_count == 2:
    print("Here is a hint: "+ hintA)
    guess_count+=1
  
  elif guess_count != guess_limit:
    guess_count += 1
  
  else:
    out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
  print("You have been locked out!")
else:
  print("Correct password!")
```

Output:

```
What's the password?
         you have 5 chances to get it right! 


Enter guess: red
Enter guess: blue
Enter guess: yellow
Here is a hint: Ashtons' favorite color
Enter guess: purple
Enter guess: beige
Enter guess: light green
You have been locked out!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secret_word, guess_limit, hintA = "green", 5, "Here is a hint: Ashtons' favorite color"

print("\t\t\tWhat's the password?\n\tyou have " + str(guess_limit) + " chances to get it right!\n")

for i in range(guess_limit):
    if i > guess_limit // 2:  # more than half of the attempts are exhausted
        print(hintA)
    if input("Enter guess: ") == secret_word:
        print("Correct password!")
        break
else:
    print("You have been locked out!")
```